# Is JSF still relevant with Microprofile

Tags: jsf, microservices, jakarta-ee

Still lost in the world of Microservices.
Is JSF still relevant with Microprofile and how can we migrate the UI part of a monolith application to Microservices when the same view should get data from many Microservices.

Comment: Microservices are not the solution to Every Problem is some want you to Believe

Comment: I believe that it is the Solution to mine. My monolith app is getting bigger and bigger with more than 50 modules. For any update of one of them, I have to redeploy the whole application: that means chatting down all other modules even if they are not concerned by the update. So @Kukeltje, do u have any suggestions?

Comment: Then you have a bad design for which you think microservices are the 'solution'. Combining several small microservices based views into a usable app introduces other 'problems', testing and integration wise. My JSF app always used (micro) services, either local or remote. Maybe your application does too much but that is not caused by JSF but by the general architecture.  A good deploy mechanism where you can do this rolling prevents downtime in general. We do this all the time when just updating some 'small' service and have no problems.

Comment: Thank you for your analysis. Any concrete suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are developing a JSF frontend, then you can envision having a microservice that could respond to each page, or each piece of specific functionality in your application. So instead of having a "monolithic" JSF backed, you could have multiple microservice backends.

Although tis is technically possible, you have to consider if it is he best way ahead for your scenario.  For example, if you use multiple microservices, what will happen to your session state, or how will your individual microservices talk to each other ?

When we think of microservices, we typically think of REST endpoints (although a microservice doesn't need to be REST based).  So, if you want to use microservice REST endpoints, maybe some sort of JavaScript view would be more efficient?

In short, you can use microservices, but you need to establish if there is a benefit for this, or if having a traditional JSF application is best.

MicroProfile itself does not support JSF, but certainly supports REST endpoints.  If you want to use JSF, you would need to use parts of Java/Jakarta EE as well as MicroProfile.

Comment: Many thanks @David. I think I will try your first suggestion: will try to move some backend business to microservice. I will share my experience later here on this post.